# iPhone CLLocationManager TrueHeading iPhoneSimulator

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

In the iPhone Simulator the CLLocationManager's UpdateHeading gives a value of 103.27 for TrueHeading.

I understand that these values are hard coded to Apple's world HQ in California.

But shouldn't TrueNorth from CA be under 45 degrees?

Comment: who cares it some hard coded value...

Comment: but if you don't own an iPhone, you rely on those values for testing. My country doesn't sell them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to change that besides over riding the value in code.